# Making a loop to extract several timelines

Tags: r, loops, rtweet

I am using the Rtweet package to obtain tweets information for every user included on a dataframe consisting on observations such as the following:

| tw usernames |
| --- |
| 'John Doe' |
| 'Frank Foe' |
| '@Larry Loe' |

This would be achieved with the **get_timeline** function as a loop. However, using the simplest loop such as:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(tw usernames)) {
timelines[[i]] <- get_timeline(i, n = 20, token = NULL)
}
```

Does not return results for any of the observations which would be obtained through the manual form:

```
timelinejohndoe <- get_timeline('JohnDoe', n = 20, token = NULL)
```

Is it a matter of how the column data frame is specified as string variables?, or is there any other approach to construct a simple loop, such as using numerical user id's instead of string variables (Which would have to be obtained regardless using a loop)?

Comment: You're overwriting `timelines` every iteration. Before the loop, initialize `timelines <- list()` and inside the loop assign `timelines[[i]] <- get_timeline...`

Comment: I will clarify this statement in the code, I have a problem starting from the first iteration since the loop is formulated poorly, failing to extract the 'John Doe' timeline when using it as a loop. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ah, I see another problem. `i` is an integer. Of course `get_timeline(1, n = 20, token = NULL)` wouldn't work. And `tw usernames` with a space in it isn't a valid identifier. So you need a vector of usernames. Something like `for(i in seq_along(vector_of_usernames)) {timelines[[i]] <- get_timeline(vector_of_usernames[i], n = 20, token = NULL)
}`. If you need more help, please share a small reproducible sample of whatever your user name vector/list/dataframe is.